# Swift : Making a get request to Get source code

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, http, get

I'm trying to make a request to get the source code.

I tried two different methods. Both kind of worked.

But both methods don't return the same source code that the real one, and by the real one i mean when i am on the website with firefox for example, and i right click and display the source code.

The source code from the website on firefox has more information that the code returned by my method in swift.

What can explain that ?

My code :

```
class RequestApi {

    func getMCPage() {

        //propertiesMap = ReadProperties.getProperties()

        let urlPath = "http://www.memecenter.com"
        let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath as String)!
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

            if((error) != nil) {
                // Si une erreur survient lors de la requête web, l'afficher en console
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }

            print("response : \(response)")
            let strData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print(strData!)

        })
        task.resume()

    }

    func getMCPage2() {
        let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.memecenter.com")!
        do {
            let urlContents = try NSString(contentsOfURL: url, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
            print(urlContents)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

method 1 and 2 return the same thing, which is different from the real one from the website.

Thx

Comment: The web site could render differently on the server side based on headers such as the user agent or session cookies or it may have JavaScript that modifies the html on the client side

Comment: The issue is indeed with the user agent, is it possible to set my own user agent in nsurlconnection or nsurlsession ? Because i don't want the default one, the source code i need from this url is with a casual webbrowser like firefox, not the user agent of a mobile browser

Answer (score 0):

As Paulw11 said, it is because my request was sent with a mobile user-agent a this website renders differently on mobile devices.
Changing the user-agent to a usual webbrowser fixed my issue.